# Loopcut and Scale

Tags: modeling, transforms, edges, shortcut, loop

I'm new to blender, I'm watching this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGmS9gKreDU at minute 2:34 there is a loop cut, and the scaling of the two edges. I did the loop cut on my model, but when I press S for scale the distance between the two edges doesn't work. What happens seems to be an extrusion. [image]
anyone can help me?

Comment: Make sure to scale on the Z-axis only - So the whole thing is Ctrl+R (Loop Cut) > Mousewheel up (make 2 cuts) > Click to set > S (Scale) > Z (Z-axis).

Comment: yeah now work, thanks a lot for the tip.